# "Value of optional type 'Set<String>?' must be unwrapped", but I didn't ask for an optional

Tags: swift

Xcode complains "Value of optional type 'Set?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'contains' of wrapped base type 'Set'"

Here's the function:

```
func talks_to (_ dialog_dict: Dictionary<String, Set<String>>, one: String, two: String) -> Bool {
        return dialog_dict[one].contains(two)
    }
```

This is a nested function, meant only to make logic clearer, and the parameters are guaranteed to be non-nil by the outer code. How do I get swift to understand this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it

```
return dialog_dict[one]?.contains(two) == true
```

or

```
return dialog_dict[one]!.contains(two)
```

this `dialog_dict[one]` returns optional

Comment: The first solution is much safer since the 2nd version will crash if `dialog_dict` does not contain a value for the key `one`.

Comment: Another way you can do it is `return dialog_dict[one]?.contains(two) ?? false`, which will specify that `false` is the default value to use if `nil` is encountered.

Comment: Well, see, that's the thing. The parameter "one" will be filled by a lookup into the dictionary supplied. That's what I meant by guaranteed. After various database lookups and whatnot, the data is entirely available, no nils, no surprises, no computations.

Comment: @DuncanC sure , i added the other as an alternative but for sure it's not safe , it's right if the op is 100 % an element will  exist

Comment: @HackSaw then the other option with **!** is ok for you

Answer (score 4):

Any time you fetch an item from a dictionary using subscripting, the result is an `Optional` because the key you use might not be found. Sh_Khan gave you a nice elegant solution: (voted)

```
return dialog_dict[one]?.contains(two) == true
```

That works because nil does not equal true, but the compiler will unwrap it and check the value inside to see if it equals true if it's not nil. So if the result of `dialog_dict[one]` is nil or false, it does not equal true. Only if `dialog_dict` contains a value for the key `one` and that value is `true` does the expression return `true`.

Comment: Yeah, so this is a design surprise. I don't have a better design in mind, so I guess I have to live with "!".

Comment: No, you don't, and shouldn't, live with `!`. Use the first version from Sh_Khan's answer.

Comment: No, seriously, if this .contains lookup fails, I want the program to die. This isn't a library function, it's a convenience function inside the main business logic of the program.

Comment: All right, fair enough. As long as `dialog_dict` isn't populated from an external data source...